# Unexpected behaviour in an array with some values

Tags: php

My code is:

```
$arr=[02,05,07,08,09];
print_r($arr)
```

and output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

Why it converts `08` and `09` to `0`??

Comment: because it's a int. Set some ' inside the values

Comment: in octal there is no 08 it have number till 07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its considered as octal number. because you are starting it from zero.

```
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
$a = 0b11111111; // binary number (equivalent to 255 decimal)
```

Answer (score 10):

Numbers beginning with a zero are considered to be in base 8.

See PHP docs: [Integers - Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax).

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.